# Why is it bad if view engines encourage logic in templates

Tags: node.js, templates

I once read [this](http://www.bearfruit.org/2014/01/20/node-js-template-showdown-mustache-compared/), because I wanted to see if handlebars is the right view engine for me or rather something else.

A thing that I wonder since then is the following, why is it considered bad, if a view engine

> encourages logic in templates?

Comment: sth is not a word.

Comment: It is a fairly well know abbreviation. As far as I know.

Comment: I assumed it was short for 'Sith'

Comment: Really? I am really used to abbreviations in my live, like sth. for something. Or btw. for by the way etc. for et cetera :)

Comment: Use the [Queen's English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) when writings posts on the SE network.  This isn't Twitter.

Answer (score 5):

#### [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

The concern of templates is visual display of information.  Business logic doesn't play any part in that.

User interfaces can contain short loops that iterate over lists.  It can also contain validation logic and things like AJAX that improve interactivity.  Beyond that, it's generally all server-side, unless the application is self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Business logic doesn't belong in the view. The view should just iterate over your list of objects and output them and provide controls for facilitating change.

Comment: Well, what is, just as an example, with authentication logic?